# TwinCat issue : state change to op mode failed master state preop is insufficient

Tags: twincat

I am using TwinCat to connect to my slaves , once I am running TwinCat in config mode all slaves go to op mode. When I switch running TwinCat to run mode : error box : state change to op mode failed master state preop is insufficient. I tried to run TwinCat in ‘’ run mode’’ in order to run the plc code.

The plc code is running fine without any error . Do I need to link something? How can I resolve this problem thanks in advance

Comment: Double check that licenses are valid. I often have some problems with EtherCAT moving from PRE/SAFEOP to OP. Reason is usually that I have pending licenses or trials have expired.

Comment: Solved must mapped the input output of the device (linked)

Comment: @TariqBellachhab If you found the solution, could you please post the answer as an "answer". Please also include a screenshot if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, but I had problem with task. I imported another one, linked one variable, and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).